# variable not updating while main thread in while loop

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I'm having trouble understanding threads and how they interact with programs, I just wanted to create a delay that does not stop the entire gui, but while fumbling my way around vs community 2019 I have discovered something that I cannot understand/google. why does my variable "stickler" not update while my main thread is in the while loop?
I used a breakpoint to determine that the thread is not updating the varible. it also does not work without the breakpoint.

```
    using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace dang_2_22_21
{
    public partial class C5E9 : Form
    {
        public C5E9()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void C5E9_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }


        static volatile int stickler;
        public void AAAAAA()
        {
            stickler++;
            textBox1.Invoke((Action)delegate
           {
               textBox1.Text = stickler.ToString() + "ms(not)";
           });
        }

        private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        public void sleeper(int time)
        {
            time = time + stickler;
            while (time > stickler)
            {
                //hehehehehheehheheheeheheheehheheheheehehehhehehehhehehehehehehheehehheheeeheheheheheheeeeehehhhhheheheheeeehehehehehhehehhehehehehhehehhehehheehehhehehehehehehhe
                //i hope this work.
                //it doont.
                //timer is on the same thread, whY?
            }
        }
        private void NumericUpDown2_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            decimal result;
            decimal start;
            start = numericUpDown2.Value;
            result = start;

            while (true)
            {
                start--;
                if (start == 0)
                {
                    break;
                }
                result = result * start;
                sleeper(100);
                numericUpDown3.Value = result;
            }
        }

        private void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(AAAAAA));
            t.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not your downvoter, but which code are we looking at?  It sounds like the TextBox, but you have the NumericUpDown in there, too.

Comment: Ok, so there's one thread that handles updating the UI, it's called the UI thread. Any event handlers that are invoked are done so on the UI thread, so by looping in that thread you are blocking the UI from updating. As someone has answered, use aync because getting this stuff right is not simple and async makes threading much easier. You can also use a background task, but async is the *modern* equivalent.

Comment: Note that `volatile` probably doesn't do what you think it does, it is only a half-barrier. For full memory barrier and cache-line skipping, use `Interlocked.Read`

Answer (score 1):

To have a "sleeping" without blocking UI use asynchornous approach.

```
private async void NumericUpDown2_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var start = numericUpDown2.Value;
    var result = start;

    while (start > 0)
    {
        start--;
        
        result = result * start;
        await Task.Delay(100); // "sleeping" for 100 milliseconds
        numericUpDown3.Value = result;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much! this is probably way easier than threading!